# First tab not opening automatically on pageload

Tags: javascript, tags, pageload

I'm trying to build a page that the content changes when you click on the tab.  I got the basic code from w3school but I can't get the first tab to open when the page loads.  Please help me find what I am doing wrong.  I'm a beginner with javascript.

Here's the code I'm using (it's the code from w3school that's supposed to have the first tab open on page load.).  I have the script in an external file and have the script tag in the header section.

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
  function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }

  // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Here's the site http://pt6-dev.info/donate-now/

Any help is appreciated!!
Peggy

Comment: It seems like It is working already

Comment: @NishantDixit - No, it isn't working.

Comment: @Peggy - you need to look at the developer tools console. it is an invaluable tool. There is an error there that you need to see. Then come ask about that error.

Comment: Thank you Randy!  I will take a look.  This came straight from w3school, is it not correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you have placed your JS in the head, so this statement:

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

is executing before the DOM has been created.

The simplest solution would be to move your JS file at the end of the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Tab.js with this code :)

You need call `document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();` when view will get prepare.

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}



   window.onload = function(e){ 
      document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
   }    

  $(document).ready(function() {  //If you are using jquery then use this other wise you can use normal window.onload
     document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the click function inside a function and call it.
that is instead of

```
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
 document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

You can add it within a function to load the window

```
window.onload = function () {
                firstTab();
            };

        function firstTab() {
            document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line of code in the end of your JavaScript

```
window.onload=function(){
    openCity(event, 'London');
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!! I added it but it didn't work.  Do you see anything else that could work?

Comment: @Peggy - it doesn't work because there is nothing called `event` at that point in the code - that code will throw an error. Don't use this code.

Comment: window.onload=function(){} @peggy can you please try it wrapping inside an onload function?

Comment: @AlexisToby - I removed my downvote. thanks for fixing your answer.

Comment: @randyCasbum Thank you.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I have another question.  I have styled everything to how I want it, the only thing I can't get to work is the square above the tab title is supposed to be a light green background color on hover and for the active tab.  The hover works but not the active.  I am using a:active.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Peggy, first you please try to close this active question by accepting any of the answers, which will be helpful for future references. And please raise you concern in more detail. Thank you.